# Grabbing an image from frame grabber as fast as possble

Tags: c++, opencv

I probably have a trivial question, I'm sorry if thats the case. 
I'm using a frame grabber (AV.io 4k) in combination with a camera and I want to grab the most recent frame with OpenCV. I wrote a test script to display the most recent image with VideoCapture::read and it works:

```
while (true) 
{
    Mat cameraFrame;
    stream1.read(cameraFrame);
    imshow("cam", cameraFrame);
    if (waitKey(30) >= 0)
        break;
}
return 0;
```

}

My question is now, how can I access the image in the RAM? I want to do further image processing in realtime and therefore want to get the pointer to the image in my memory. Is there a way?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: opencv uses some kind of reference counting, cv::Mat pixel data isn't copied if not copied explicitly. During frame grabbing, typically some preprocessings occur, like demuxing, decoding, color space conversion. In OpenCV you dont have access to these steps, you'll just get the BGR image. Afaik, you can't really speed-up the .read method (unless changing resolution or similar). What kind of behaviour do you observe and where's the problem?

Comment: Your question is a little broad. If your processes are fast enough you can do them on cameraFrame itself. But It's a better job to copy cameraFrame to another Mat and then do the processing. The memory location of the original image you're looking for gets replaced every x miliseconds (x=1000/FrameRate), so you have to copy the image somewhere else and do the other stuff you want to do.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. It was "uchar* cv::Mat::data" I was looking for:
https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a4d33bed1c850265370d2af0ff02e1564